# Regex match repeated digits without sorting

Tags: javascript, regex

In a string like this

```js
16,17,22,22,22,22,20,16
```

I'm trying to match the repeated digits without sorting.

I tried `(\d+)\1+` and many variations but it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "without sorting"? And what result are you expecting?

Comment: I mean i don't want to split and sort and join again.
The result I expect would be an array of the digits that repeat in the string  `[16, 22, 22, 22, 22, 16]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
console.log("16,17,22,22,22,22,20,16".match(
     /\b(\d+)\b(?:(?<=\b\1\b.*\b\1\b)|(?=.*\b\1\b))/g
))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PGN5n2/1)

**Details**

- `\b(\d+)\b` - one or more digits captured into Group 1 that are enclosed with word boundaries
- `(?:(?<=\b\1\b.*\b\1\b)|(?=.*\b\1\b))` - a non-capturing group matching either of the two patterns:

  - `(?<=\b\1\b.*\b\1\b)` - a location immediately preceded with the same value as captured in Group 1 (as a whole word), then any zero or more chars other than line break chars and again such value as in Group 1 (this second one just matches what `\b(\d+)\b` matched since the lookbehind is located after the Group 1)
  - `|` - or
  - `(?=.*\b\1\b)` - a location immediately followed with any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then Group 1 value as a whole word.